# Implementing std::bit_cast equivalent in C

Tags: c, macros, typeof, type-punning, c23

Is it possible to implement something similar to C++20's [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) in C? It would be a lot more convenient than using `union` or casting pointers to different types and dereferencing.

If you had a `bit_cast`, then implementing some floating point functions would be easier:

```c
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    int i = 0x5f3759df - ( bit_cast(int, number) >> 1 );
    
    float y = bit_cast(float, i);
    y = y * ( 1.5f - ( number * 0.5f * y * y ) );
    y = y * ( 1.5f - ( number * 0.5f * y * y ) );
    
    return y;
}
```

See also [Fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

The naive solution is:

```c
#define bit_cast(T, ...) (*(T*) &(__VA_ARGS__))
```

But it has major problems:

1. it is undefined behavior because it violates strict aliasing
2. it doesn't work for bit-casting rvalues because we are taking the address of the second operand directly
3. it doesn't make sure that the operands have the same size

Can we implement a `bit_cast` without these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in non-standard standard C, thanks to `typeof`. [`typeof` is also a further proposed feature for C23](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2724.htm), so it may become possible in standard C23. One of the solutions below makes some sacrifices which allow C99 compliance.

### Implementation Using `union`

Let's look at how the approach using `union` works first:

```c
#define bit_cast(T, ...) \
  ((union{typeof(T) a; typeof(__VA_ARGS__) b;}) {.b=(__VA_ARGS__)}.a)
```

We are creating a compound literal from an anonymous union made of `T` and whatever type the given expression has. We initialize this literal to `.b= ...` using designated initializers and then access the `.a` member of type `T`.

The `typeof(T)` is necessary if we want to pun function pointers, arrays, etc., due to C's type syntax.

### Implementation using `memcpy`

This implementation is slightly longer, but has the advantage of relying only on C99, and can even work without the use of `typeof`:

```c
#define bit_cast(T, ...) \
    (*(typeof(T)*) memcpy(&(T){0}, &(typeof(__VA_ARGS__)) {(__VA_ARGS__)}, sizeof(T)))
```

We are copying from one compound literal to another and then accessing the destination's value:

- the source literal is a copy of our input expression, which allows us to take its address, even for `bit_cast(float, 123)` where `123` is an rvalue
- the destination is a zero-initialized literal of type `T`

`memcpy` returns the destination operand, so we can cast the result to `typeof(T)*` and then dereference that pointer.

We can completely eliminate `typeof` here and make this C99-compliant, but there are downsides:

```c
#define bit_cast(T, ...) \
    (*((T*) memcpy(&(T){0}, &(__VA_ARGS__), sizeof(T))))
```

We are now taking the address of the expression directly, so we can't use `bit_cast` on rvalues anymore. We are using `T*` without `typeof`, so we can no longer convert to function pointers, arrays, etc.

### Implementing Size Checking (since C11)

As for the last issue, which is that we don't verify that both operands have the same size: We can use `_Static_assert` (since C11) to make sure of that. Unfortunately, `_Static_assert` is a declaration, not an expression, so we have to wrap it up:

```c
#define static_assert_expr(...) \
    ((void) (struct{_Static_assert(__VA_ARGS__); int _;}) {0})
```

We are creating a compound literal that contains the assertion and discarding the expression.

We can easily integrate this in the previous two implementations using the comma operator:

```c
#define bit_cast_memcpy(T, ...) ( \
    static_assert_expr(sizeof(T) == sizeof(__VA_ARGS__), "operands must have the same size"), \
    (*(typeof(T)*) memcpy(&(T){0}, &(typeof(__VA_ARGS__)) {(__VA_ARGS__)}, sizeof(T))) \
)

#define bit_cast_union(T, ...) ( \
    static_assert_expr(sizeof(T) == sizeof(__VA_ARGS__), "operands must have the same size"), \
    ((union{typeof(T) a; typeof(__VA_ARGS__) b;}) {.b=(__VA_ARGS__)}.a) \
)
```

### Known and Unfixable Issues

Because of how macros work, we can not use this if the punned type contains a comma:

```c
bit_cast(int[0,1], x)
```

This doesn't work because macros ignore square brackets and the `1]` would not be considered part of the type, but would go into `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: consider passing the type of the value as the second  parameter of the macro. Sometimes expressions have a very different type that the operands like adding two `char`. It would let use cast-by-union without typeof. Alternatively, disallow passing r-values

Comment: @tstanisl Passing any types creates some unfixable issues, and having to pass two types is redundant in many cases. You can also `bit_cast(float, (int) x)` so an extra type parameter would be very redundant. But still, I like that it works with rvalues and makes the union-based solution C89-compliant.

Disallowing rvalues is not a bad option, and it saves one compound literal and use of `typeof`, so it's not a bad workaround.